# ARKit : how to init didAddNode?

Tags: objective-c, swift, arkit

Every time a new anchor is detected, the following delegate method is launched once:

```
- (void)renderer:(id <SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor
```

I wonder how to make so that all the anchors already detected are 'forgotten' and might be detected again.

Answer in Swift and/or Obj C.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your Q. What do you mean with "forgotten"?

Comment: This delegate method is called just once when a new surface is detected. I would like to clean all the detection history in order to be able to detect again a surface already detected.

Comment: This method is called, when a new node is added. Even the old nodes are "forgotten", they cannot be added newly. When should the method be called? Why doesn't you scan for the existing nodes? Maybe it would be better, if you describe your goal behind this Q.